# NEO4J find records that not exist in other pattern result

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm new to Graph Database world, i just started to learn neo4j.

For example. I have a list of all video and a list of user watched video. How do I write pattern to query a list of not watched video based on specifed user id ?

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your labelled property model looks something like this:

- Some nodes with label "USER" for the users
- Some nodes with label "MOVIE" for the movies
- Some Relations of type "Has_Watched" to indicate a user has seen the movie

Then you can do something like this:

```
MATCH (user:USER)
WHERE user.Id = $yourId
MATCH (movie:MOVIE)
WITH user, movie
MATCH (user)
WHERE IsEmpty((user)-[:HAS_WATCHED]->(movie))
RETURN movie
```

So basically you get your user by ID and you get all movies. Then you only look for the movies that are not connected via a relationship of type "HAS_WATCHED".

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved my problem.

But, i have another question. If i have about 10M video, and user watched about 100K video. Does above query work good ? 

Or. Should I have all watched video ? Please suggest me.

Comment: Post another /followup SO question about it

Comment: I have a similar problem where along with fetching all the non-connected users and movies, I need to fetch all the movies where user and movie have a `HAS_WATCHED` relationship, but the `status` attribute of the relationship is `DELETED`. Is is possible to do in the same query? Also, is there a link for the follow question as I may have a similar problem of having a lot of users and movies?

Comment: I used a UNION query for this, but that's not giving me the desired result